# Position: fixed on the navigation bar but my footer is stacking on top of it when I click the open navigation button

Tags: html, css

I have created a close and open button for my navigation. I have position fixed on my nav property. When I click the open button,  the navigation opens and covers my whole page as intended EXCEPT for my footer? My footer is still visible, on top of the nav. I can't figure out what might be causing that. I've included the code for the nav and footer.Suggestions much appreciated!

```
    /* navigation */ 
    
    .header {
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .header-content {
        display: flex;
        grid-column: 2 / -2;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .nav {
        position: fixed;
        background: #001E39;
        width: 100%;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:100%;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .nav-list {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav-link { 
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    /* --- nav-buttons --- */
    
    .navigation-open {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    
    .close-nav {
        border: 0;
        background: 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 2rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: .5em;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .open-nav {
        border: 0;
        font-size: 2rem;
        background: 0;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: .5em;
        margin-left: auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 420px;
        top: 8px;
    }
    /*================= */
    /*     FOOTER       */
    /*==================*/

    .footer {
        background: #0B2458;
        opacity: .8;
        color: #fff;
        padding: .5em;
    }

    .footer-text {
        grid-column: 2;
    }
```

Comment: A reproducible example on jsfiddle would really help here, and allow others to offer suggestions.

Comment: life saver, thanks for that! didn't even know about jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

the footer didn't post, my bad.
this is the code. thank you.

```
/*================= */
/*     FOOTER       */
/*==================*/

.footer {
    background: #0B2458;
    opacity: .8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: .5em;
}

.footer-text {
    grid-column: 2;
}
```

Comment: i believe this footer styling is for above question. in that case you can delete this which is posted incase of answer.